What is the type of this connector?
I have to find the female connector for this male one. I do not want to use all the pins so I would be happy with a configurable mother connector. Is that existing? Many thanks in advance!


I would call that a female connector - the contacts have holes to accept male pins.

It looks a lot like, Molex Mini-Fit Jr
I think in-line shells and crimp pins are available.

Thanks a lot! :)
